# set data attribute in grouped_collection_select dynamically in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form like this in my orders/new page. I have used this to select model location and then choose a model from the location according to what is selected in the above select box.

```
<%= f.label "SELECT MODEL LOCATION *" %>
          <div class="list_number">1</div><%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :formatted_display, prompt: true, :required => true,  :class => 'chosen-select' %>

          <%= f.label "SELECT YOUR MODEL *" %>
          <div class="list_number">2</div>
          <%= f.grouped_collection_select :performer_id, Location.order(:name).map{|group| Performer.find_by_location_id(group.id).map{|performer| {'data-markup'=>performer.white_label.markup}}}, :performers, :name, :id, :first_name, include_blank: true, :required => true,  class: 'chosen-select' %>
```

In the grouped_collection_select when I use map to set the data attribute I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `map' for #<Performer:0x00000006813958>
```

How do I solve this error and get the data required?

---

After trying  the below code

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :performer_id, Location.order(:name).map{|group| Performer.where(location_id: group.id).map{|performer| {'data-markup'=>performer.white_label.markup}}}, :performers, :name, :id, :first_name, include_blank: true, :required => true,  class: 'chosen-select' %>
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `performers' for [{"data-markup"=>#<BigDecimal:67e80c8,'0.0',9(36)>}]:Array
```

When I tried the following

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :performer_id, Location.order(:name), :performers, :name, :id, :first_name,Location.order(:name).map{|group| Performer.where(location_id: group.id).map{|performer| {'data-markup'=>performer.white_label.markup}}}, include_blank: true, :required => true,  class: 'chosen-select' %>
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `merge' for #<Array:0x000000069705a8>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Performer.find_by_location_id(group.id)
```

returns an instance but `map` is method for Array. 
The fix depends on your business logic (and APP structure)
You can use `Performer.where(location_id: group.id).map...` if there are many Performers

I think you try to use this helper wrongly. According to [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select) you should pass a `collection` and `group_method`. `group_method - The name of a method which, when called on a member of collection, returns an array of child objects representing the <option> tags.`

You pass an array of objects `[{'data-markup' => some_value}, ...]` as collection and `performers` as group_method. Rails try to call `{'data-markup' => some_value}.performers` and this raises an exception.

You should rewrite a collection the following way:
1. it should be array
2. each item of array should have method `performers` - which return an array of objects under one group item

I hope it will help you

I can't test but it can work (if Location has_many performers or you can implement your own method according to your business logic)

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :performer_id, Location.order(:name), :performers, :name, :id, :first_name, include_blank: true, :required => true,  class: 'chosen-select' %>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting this error undefined method `performers' for [{"data-markup"=>#<BigDecimal:68cef78,'0.0',9(36)>}]:Array

Comment: post your new variant

Comment: `Location.order(:name).map{|group| Performer.where(location_id: group.id).map{|performer| {'data-markup'=>performer.white_label.markup}}}`

undefined method `merge' for #<Array:0x000000067e2da8>

Comment: there is no `merge` in this code - I think it fails in other place

Comment: I update the answer. I think I understood what is wrong and tried to explain what is wrong, but I don't know right now how to build `collection` as you want.